# Oauth for a third-party app through Salesforce Community

Tags: oauth, salesforce-communities

I'm trying to set up Oauth for the Cadmium Elevate learning management system so that our Overage Customer Portal users can log into the Cadmium system.

I set up a connected app and shared the client ID and secret with the developers at Cadmium.

The users were initially just authorized for a Salesforce Site, but Cadmium could not reach the services endpoints. So I created a Community/Experience (which is active and allows login, but the Builder pages are not published) and gave the same users access to that system. Cadmium can now log into the community and hit the services but they say that the Oauth credentials are being rejected.

Can anyone help guide me through this? I'm new to Oauth.